# Using pipes to delete all occurences of Thumbs.db file from Ubuntu Laptop

Tags: ubuntu, pipe, pipeline

I have a laptop installed with Ubuntu 10.04. I migrated some of my files from one computer to this computer. But there are some files like Thumbs.db file whose every occurrence I want to get rid of.

I tried using

```
locate Thumbs.db | rm
```

But dis didn't worked out (and clearly it should not). Then I tried using following, but quite expectedly none of them worked out :

```
locate thumbs.db > rm
locate thumbs.db < rm
```

As everyone here, might have pointed out that I am having a hard time using pipeline and want to just clear my concept using this as an example. I have read the basics but still not able to intitutively able to apply it.

Answer (score 13):

`find` already has a delete function, so no pipes are necessary:

```
find . -iname thumbs.db -delete
```

This says delete all files matching `thumbs.db` regardless of capitalization, recursively from my current working directory.

Comment: @w2lame: Also try `find . -iname *.ini -delete` if you want to get rid of those files too.

Comment: This was very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want try:

```
find /mnt/something -iname 'thumbs.db' -exec rm -v {} \;
```

or if you really want use pipe you may want try

```
find /mnt/something -iname 'thumbs.db' | xargs rm -v
```

`-iname` will search for 'Thumbs.db' and 'thumbs.db'. Check man for more info.

change `/mnt/something` for your path.

Edit:

I think you can also try it:

```
find /mnt/someting -iname 'thumbs.db' | while read junk; do rm -v "$junk"; done
```

It should work with dirs what contain space in name etc.

Comment: One problem with the above is that say I have a directory "New Directory" which have Thumbs.db file. When I issue the above command it tries to delete Thumbs.db from "New" and "Directory" directories which doesn't exist on my computer.

Comment: Thats where pipe and xargs sucks, if you will use the one with -exec it will work as you want.

Comment: find and xargs don't suck. Just use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`. This uses null characters to separate the filename, so spaces are no longer special.

Comment: @Ryan can you please elaboarate more on its usage or edit the code of Piotr to meet the requirement

Comment: `find /mnt/something -iname 'thumbs.db' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -v`